# Anti resonance frequency of piezoelectric

Tags: piezoelectric

There is a method to measure anti resonance frequency of piezoelectric? The RC circuit and this relation and equations can measure resonance frequency.

Comment: Related questions by OP [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/451551/44126) and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/451647/44126).

Comment: unclear what you mean by "antiresonance".

Comment: Anti resonance frequency is a frequency that impedance is maximum.